# How to check a number of inserted/modified records in TADOCommand?

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, ado, rowcount

I am using SQL Server database and after calling a simple SQL script I would like to know how many records were affected by last (or only) executed statement in a script.

I cannot find the reference how to achieve this in Delphi's TADOCommand and I know SQL Server gives this information to provider. I am aware of workarounds like getting @@ROWCOUNT in another query, yet this gives some overhead and unnecessary complexity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use the

```
function Execute(var RecordsAffected: Integer; const Parameters: OleVariant): _Recordset;
```

version of the Execute method?

From the [doc](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOCommand_Execute.html):

> RecordsAffected indicates the number
>   of records, if the command operates on
>   data, that are affected by the command
>   after execution.

So that should give you what you need.

Disclaimer: I cannot test this against SQL Server (don't have it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was not aware of this set of arguments.

Unfortunatelly, as I've just checked, affected records variable is still 0 after Execute :(

cmd := TADOCommand.Create(nil);
cmd.Commandtext := 'DELETE FROM void';
ra := 0;
cmd.Execute(ra, 0);
Assert(ra > 0);

Comment: What is `DELETE FROM void` supposed to do? And are you sure any records are in fact affected?

Comment: void is an example table name, so the statement deletes all records from table [dbo].[void]. I am sure that there are records in the table, I tested it on simple application as well.

Comment: Well, either your table is in fact already empty or something is wrong with your provider, or ... I just tested a `DELETE FROM <table>` with a TAdoCommand against an MS Access database and got exactly the number of records deleted returned through the `RecordsAffected` var parameter.